# how to query nullable datetime in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am calling the following query, to display only latest date from fieldname 'UploadDate', however I am experiencing exception error such as:

> The entity or complex type 'cdwModel.database_BD' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.","ExceptionType":"System.NotSupportedException","StackTrace":

Code:

```
public IEnumerable<database_BD> GetDate()
    {
        var data = (from c in db.database_BD
           select new database_BD()
           {
               UploadDate = c.UploadDate

           }).ToList().OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate).Take(1);

         return data;
    }
```

database_BD model class:

```
public partial class database_BD
 {
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UploadDate { get; set; }
 }
```

Working solution:

```
public DateTime? GetDate()
    {
        return data = db.database_BD.Select(d => d.UploadDate)
                     .OrderByDescending(c => c)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Is this Linq-To-Sql or Entity Framework (they are two separate frameworks)?

Comment: apology for the confusion, the data model was created using entity framework. sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to display the latest date from `UploadDate`, then you dont need to create a new database object.

In this example data will be a single date value, or null if there are no records:

```
var data = db.database_BD.Select(d => d.UploadDate)
                         .OrderByDescending(c => c)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you need to return a `database_BD` object, you'd remove the select which changes the output:

```
public database_BD GetDate()
{
    var data = db.database_BD.OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate)
                             .FirstOrDefault(a => a.UploadDate.HasValue);
     return data;
}
```

That will give you the newest `database_BD` object in your table.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I have already tried this approach and this code gives me the -- Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<API_09.database_BD> -- error, on the return data; line code.

Comment: Oh.. you have already defined `data` previously?  If you use my code as it is, you wont get that error.  Perhaps your problem is that your code says it wants an enumerable of `API_09.database_BD`, but you only want to pull the date.

Comment: @user3070072 if you can change your method to only return one object use what i have posted above, otherwise go with Erik's answer

Comment: @user3070072, did you find your answer?

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I manage to get the code to work by changing the swapping couple of code. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since your field is nullable you probablye want:

```
IEnumerable<database_BD> data = db.database_BD
  .Where(d => d.UpdateDate.HasValue)
  .OrderByDescending(d => d.UpdateDate.Value)
  .Take(1);
```

**updated per your change in the question**

Comment: hi, I am sorry to inform, but the code above gives error --- Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<API_09.database_BD> -- error, on the return data; line code. Does this issue indicate, i would need to parse the uploadDate fieldname?

Comment: I'm am extremely confident that my code example would not throw an exception unless you changed it.  I've explicitly set the type for data, so unless your `UpdateDate` is not a `Nullable<DateTime>` it should work exactly as I posted.

Comment: A `FirstOrDefault` wouldnt return an enumerable Erik, it would return the object.  Or am i missing something?

Comment: The question was definitely ambiguous, did my best to answer it accordingly and of course as I changed to meet the more precise question it broke it.